# Which random generator does /dev/urandom use (LTS 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, kernel, encryption, security, source-code

I am curious about the standard cryptographic secure random generator used by `/dev/urandom` in Ubuntu LTS 20.04. Can someone name the standard or provide me with a reference where I can find more information, e.g. the source code?

Comment: If you're familiar with git, [maybe here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/crng/random.git/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the **"the kernel's random number generator"** as stated in [`man 4 random, urandom`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man4/random.4.html):

> The  character  special  files  /dev/random  and /dev/urandom (present
> since Linux 1.3.30) provide an interface to the kernel's random number
> generator.  The  file  /dev/random  has major  device  number 1 and
> minor device number 8.  The file /dev/urandom has major device number
> 1 and minor device number 9.
>
> The random number generator gathers environmental noise  from  device
> drivers  and  other sources  into an entropy pool.  The generator also
> keeps an estimate of the number of bits of noise in the entropy pool.
> From this entropy pool, random numbers are created.

More is explained in the programmers' comments of the kernel's related source file [`random.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c?id=refs/tags/v3.15.6#n52):

```
 * This routine gathers environmental noise from device drivers, etc.,
 * and returns good random numbers, suitable for cryptographic use.
 * Besides the obvious cryptographic uses, these numbers are also good
 * for seeding TCP sequence numbers, and other places where it is
 * desirable to have numbers which are not only random, but hard to
 * predict by an attacker.
 *
 * Theory of operation
 * ===================
 *
 * Computers are very predictable devices.  Hence it is extremely hard
 * to produce truly random numbers on a computer --- as opposed to
 * pseudo-random numbers, which can easily generated by using a
 * algorithm.  Unfortunately, it is very easy for attackers to guess
 * the sequence of pseudo-random number generators, and for some
 * applications this is not acceptable.  So instead, we must try to
 * gather "environmental noise" from the computer's environment, which
 * must be hard for outside attackers to observe, and use that to
 * generate random numbers.  In a Unix environment, this is best done
 * from inside the kernel.
 *
 * Sources of randomness from the environment include inter-keyboard
 * timings, inter-interrupt timings from some interrupts, and other
 * events which are both (a) non-deterministic and (b) hard for an
 * outside observer to measure.  Randomness from these sources are
 * added to an "entropy pool", which is mixed using a CRC-like function.
 * This is not cryptographically strong, but it is adequate assuming
 * the randomness is not chosen maliciously, and it is fast enough that
 * the overhead of doing it on every interrupt is very reasonable.
 * As random bytes are mixed into the entropy pool, the routines keep
 * an *estimate* of how many bits of randomness have been stored into
 * the random number generator's internal state.
 *
 * When random bytes are desired, they are obtained by taking the SHA
 * hash of the contents of the "entropy pool".  The SHA hash avoids
 * exposing the internal state of the entropy pool.  It is believed to
 * be computationally infeasible to derive any useful information
 * about the input of SHA from its output.  Even if it is possible to
 * analyze SHA in some clever way, as long as the amount of data
 * returned from the generator is less than the inherent entropy in
 * the pool, the output data is totally unpredictable.  For this
 * reason, the routine decreases its internal estimate of how many
 * bits of "true randomness" are contained in the entropy pool as it
 * outputs random numbers.
 *
 * If this estimate goes to zero, the routine can still generate
 * random numbers; however, an attacker may (at least in theory) be
 * able to infer the future output of the generator from prior
 * outputs.  This requires successful cryptanalysis of SHA, which is
 * not believed to be feasible, but there is a remote possibility.
 * Nonetheless, these numbers should be useful for the vast majority
 * of purposes.
```